# How to get Sender Button Tag/Name/ID in UIImagePickerController - didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Can somebody guide me on getting the `sender button Tag/Name/ID` in below method?

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{

// I Want to get the sender button reference here

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use picker.view.tag to identify the UIImagePickerController type. whenever you called UIImagePicker you can set the tag of its view.

I have used the same for identifying different image picker.

**EDIT**

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePickerController.view.tag = 5;//set the tag here
```

> ```
> - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
> {
>      NSLog(@"%d",picker.view.tag);
> }
> ```

you will get the tag value wahtever you will set.

Comment: I tried this option, But I am gettin picker.view.tag value as (null). Do we need to declare something at image picker button level ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(IBAction)ownMethod:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    **imagePickerController.view.tag = [sender tag];//set the tag of button to picker tag ** 
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```